# Difference between Linker and Librarian in VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

What is the difference between Additional Library Directories in the Linker section and  in the Librarian section?

Will Visual Studio "see" .lib files when I place my directory under Linker instead of Librarian?

Thanks.

Comment: A project either has the Library section (a static lib project) OR a Linker section (everything else).  Your question therefore makes little sense.  Not starting with a project template is never not a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is your target type -- Executable or library.

Visual Studio allow you to set the Linker options when you are creating an executable.

Visual Studio uses the Librarian when you are producing (not consuming) a dynamic or static library.

The directory for Librarian is for libraries you want to reference when making a dynamic or static library.